# how to generate correct javadoc reference?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Firstly forgive me if it is a dumb question:/

I tried to generate javadoc with Eclipse but the generated documentation does not have a hyperlink for `@see` `@link` tag. (I referenced a class within the same package) Then I checked the reference path for classes it appears empty when I press ctrl+space after `@see` tag)

But when I check the javadoc path for the project it is correct and validated.

How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed-- I have created javadoc before the javadoc comments were completed and simply overwrote the old one when I finished. By deleting the whole javadoc folder and generating again the problem is fixed